# How can I make a generator which iterates over 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a huge  2D numpy array which I want to retrieve in batches. 
Array shape is=`60000,3072` I want to make a generator that gives me chunks out of this array like : `1000,3072` , then next `1000,3072` and so on. How can I make a generator to iterate over this array and pass me a batch of given size?

Comment: That a vague question.  Where is this array? What shape?  What size of a batch?  The concept of a generator isn't all that useful when dealing with numpy arrays. Depending on how/where the array is stored it is possible to select slices from it, or even copies of blocks.

Comment: `iter(np.vsplit(your_array, 60))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

consider array `a`

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12]])
```

***Option 1***
Use a generator

```
def get_every_n(a, n=2):
    for i in range(a.shape[0] // n):
        yield a[n*i:n*(i+1)]

for sa in get_every_n(a):
    print sa

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[[ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]]
```

***Option 2***
use `reshape` and `//`

```
a.reshape(a.shape[0] // 2, -1, a.shape[1])

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

***Option 3***
if you wanted groups of two rather than two groups

```
a.reshape(-1, 2, a.shape[1])

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

Since you explicitly stated that you need a generator you can use option 1 as the appropriate reference.

Comment: In Option 1, the parameter `n` doesn't seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: +1. The `reshape()` based solutions are interesting. They will work only in case of perfect divisibility, though. Please correct your Option 1 to use the parameter `n`, inside the generator function. Currently the parameter is unused.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the data that you have:

```
import numpy as np
full_len = 5    # In your case, 60_000
cols = 3        # In your case, 3072

nd1 = np.arange(full_len*cols).reshape(full_len,cols)
```

Here's what you can do, to "generate" the slices:

**Option 1, Using numpy.array_split():**

```
from math import ceil

step_size = 2   # In your case, 1_000
split_list = np.array_split(nd1,ceil(full_len/step_size), axis=0)
print (split_list)
```

`split_list` is now a list of slices into `nd1`. By looping over this list, you can access the individual slices as `split_list[0]`, `split_list[1]`, etc, and each of these slices would be a view into `nd1`, and can be used exactly as you would use any other numpy array.

Output for Option 1:

Here's the output, showing that the last slice was a bit shorter than the other regular ones:

```
[array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]]), array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]]), array([[12, 13, 14]])]
```

**Option 2, by explicit slicing:**

```
step_size = 2   # In your case, 1_000
myrange = range(0, full_len, step_size)

for r in myrange:
    my_slice_array = nd1 [r:r+step_size]
    print (my_slice_array.shape)
```

Output for Option 2:

```
(2, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 3)
```

Note that unlike slicing lists, slicing a numpy array does not make a copy of the source array's data. It only creates a view within the slice bounds, on the existing data of the source numpy array. This applies to both **Option 1**, and **Option 2**, since both involve the creation of slices.

Comment: `split` and `array_split` essentially do `[arr[i:j] for i,j in ....]` - in effect a list of slices, views.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks. I will edit accordingly (after satisfying myself with a small test). The doc seemed silent on this. :-).

Comment: @hpaulj: You're right about `array_split()`, thanks. I've edited to add the `array_split()` based solution as Option 1 (and deleted my suspicions about possible copying of data).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use a generator like suggested by ChiefAmay but his 1. solution only returns whole chunks, without returning the leftover chunk at the end. Here improved solution which returns every part of the array:

```
def get_every_n(a, n=2):
    full_chunks_len = a.shape[0] // n
    for i in range(full_chunks_len):
        yield a[n*i:n*(i+1)]
    yield a[full_chunks_len*n:]

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15]])

for chunk in get_every_n(a):
    print(chunk)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[[ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]]
[[13 14 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something in generator way, this below solution works

```
import numpy 
bigArray = numpy.random.rand(60000, 3072) # have used this to generate dummy array

def selectArray(m,n):
  yield bigArray[m, n] # I am facing issue with giving proper slices. Please handle it yourselg. 

genObject = selectArray(1000, 3072)
```

and you can use either `for` loop or `next()` to iterate over `genObject`.

Note: if you are using `next()` make sure you are handling `StopIteration` exception.

Hope it helps.